# Issue using Spring and Java Mailer, getting stuck parsing into HTML

Tags: java, spring, email

Another issue I've been trying to debug. I have a form that onClick of button it should gather info and send as an email. My debugger is telling me it is hanging up on translating that into html/ the templateEngine.process. Since inside this it's not my code, I am having trouble understanding why it is stuck there. I am also getting this error: java.io.IOException: javax.mail.MessagingException: Empty multipart: multipart/related; 
Any ideas? Below is the code it's getting stuck in.

```html
    public void sendSimpleMessage(Mail mail, DirectBind directBindMsg) throws MessagingException, IOException {
        MimeMessage message = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message,
                MimeMessageHelper.MULTIPART_MODE_MIXED_RELATED,
                StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());

        Context context = new Context();
        context.setVariables(mail.getModel());
        context.setVariable("directBind",directBindMsg);
        String html = templateEngine.process("emailMessage", context);

        helper.setTo(mail.getTo());
        helper.setText(html, true);
        helper.setSubject(mail.getSubject());
        helper.setFrom(mail.getFrom());

        javaMailSender.send(message);
    }
```

So it keeps getting sent to my catch in my Controller:

```html
    @PostMapping("/send")
    public String send(Model model, @ModelAttribute("directBind") DirectBind directBind){
        Mail mail = new Mail();
        mail.setFrom("no-reply@hgitservices.com");

        mail.setTo(new String[]{"stacief@hgitservices.com"});
        mail.setSubject("Oli Affiliate - AMS360 & PMA Data Checklist");

        Map<String, Object> mailModel = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        mail.setModel(mailModel);

        try {
            emailService.sendSimpleMessage(mail, directBind);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return ("redirect:/?sentMessageFail");
        }
        return ("redirect:/?sentMessage");
    }


    @RequestMapping(value="/email")
    public String email(){
        return "emailMessage";
    }
}
```

[image: this is where the code dies in during the debugger... inside the String html templateEngine.process.]

Comment: Could you provide a few extra details? Spring version, java version and a few more lines from the stack trace? A workaround would be providing spring.mail.properties.mail.mime.multipart.allowempty=true, but I couldn't reproduce locally this issue.

Comment: Spring 1.5.10, Java 1.8. Let me rerun and to see what I should provide from the stack trace.

Comment: I was able to fix the issue, it wasn't liking something in my html template. I am having issues grabbing the content from the form though. It is just sending an the email template with whatever is hard coded. Any idea why it isnt grabbing the form info? Do you think I need a @RequestParams in my send function?

Comment: Hard to say... Are you sending the input via Form? Using any template resolver like Thymeleaf? DirectBind object is correctly filled by the form fields? Check if you correctly binding form and object fields. I believe that the @RequestParam does not fit while using a form for input.